# Adding WHERE to a Simple LINQ Query returns zero results (but shouldn't)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I've got the following query:

```
var Query = db.ReportCommon
              .Where(x => x.ReportType == category)
              .Where(x => x.ReportDateTime >= dateStart)
              .Where(x => x.ReportDateTime < dateEnd);
```

`category` is a variable that I pass in (i.e. 'Short', 'Standard' etc);
`dateStart` and `dateEnd` are DateTime values.

This query returns results as expected (approximately 300 odd).

But when I add the following line I get zero results when in reality I should get approximately 2 or 3 less results:

```
              .Where(x => x.PartnerRef.ToUpper() != "TEST");
```

There are only about 3 entries where the `PartnerRef` field does contain 'Test' or 'test' or 'TEST' the others are either NULL or contain different Partner Refs (like 'DSW').

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is `db`? (i.e. which LINQ provider are you using?)

Comment: db is my Entity Context

private OnlineReportingEntityContext db = new OnlineReportingEntityContext();

Comment: Could you give us a readout on those rows you're expecting, straight from your SQL provider? Perhaps there's something about that PartnerRef field that isn't quite congruent with what you're expecting.

Comment: Are you sure there are no trailing spaces of your values in the database, and that's why you are not getting any matches?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the values of `category`, `dateStart`, and `dateEnd` are the same?

Also, if you use

```
.Where(x => x.PartnerRef.ToUpper() == "TEST");
```

do you get the 2 or 3 records you expect?

You might also want to try running this in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), which will allow you to experment and see the SQL that EF is generating.

Comment: Working my way through these suggestions... If I use your suggestion then, yes, I do get the records I expected. LINQPad looks interesting... I'll need to get to grips with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the SQL generated, but in SQL terms NULL != "TEST" evaluates to UNKNOWN,  not TRUE,  and so those results wouldn't be returned.

You may be hoping that EF is clever enough to spot this pitfall and emit NULL checks into the SQL,  but given everything in your question it may appear that it isn't.

Can't explain why the other PartnerRef values aren't being returned - it all points to some other external factor you haven't identified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is happening with your code.
However, if in a certain entry "PartnerRef" is null, than PartnerRef.ToUpper() would throw a null reference exception.

Can it be you are handling that exception somewhere, but result remains empty, because the query was never fulfilled?

Comment: Thanks.

I do have plenty of NULL entries, yes. But even if I remove the ToUpper() I still get the same problem...

Comment: you won't get NRE if it's the Linq to SQL QueryProvider that evaluate the query.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Databases doesn't need the .ToUpper because sql queries are not case sensitive. You might try profiling the generated SQL to find out why your query is failing. Post your SQL if you still need help.

Comment: They can be, depends on the DB collation